# Why elastic search not returning result when query contains "IN" prefix?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

Below Elastic Query is not returning any result for my application

```
"query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "simple_query_string" : {
          "query" : "IN-123456",
          "fields" : [
            "field1.auto^1.0",
            "field2.auto^1.0"
          ],
          "flags" : -1,
          "default_operator" : "AND",
          "analyze_wildcard" : false,
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_prefix_length" : 0,
          "fuzzy_max_expansions" : 50,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```

Note that I have document present in elastic data source with matching text "IN-123456" for field2. 
I am able to search same document with "123456" as text in query.

Below is the index used

```
{
  "document_****": {
    "aliases": {
      "document": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "date_detection": false,
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "field2": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "auto": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
              }
            }
          },

        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "document_***",
        "creation_date": "1****",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "autocomplete_filter_30": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": "1",
              "max_gram": "30"
            },
            "autocomplete_filter": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": "1",
              "max_gram": "20"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "stop",
                "autocomplete_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "autocomplete_30": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "stop",
                "autocomplete_filter_30"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "autocomplete_nonstop": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "autocomplete_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "***",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020499"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Few values are replaced with * for confidentiality reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing my index mapping found that token filter stop is removing the prefix **IN** from token streams. since it is part of default stop word list *english* stop words

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html

Because of this elastic search is ignoring the prefix IN while searching and not returning any result

Answer (score 0):

Check your mapping. The below query working fine.

```
POST v_upload_branch/_doc
{
  "branch_name":"IN-123456", 
  "branch_head":"Chennai", 
}

GET v_upload_branch/_search
{
"query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "simple_query_string" : {
          "query" : "IN-123456",
          "fields" : [
            "branch_head^1.0",
            "branch_name^1.0"
          ],
          "flags" : -1,
          "default_operator" : "AND",
          "analyze_wildcard" : false,
          "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
          "fuzzy_prefix_length" : 0,
          "fuzzy_max_expansions" : 50,
          "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```

Below is the index used

```
{
  "document_****": {
    "aliases": {
      "document": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "date_detection": false,
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "field2": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "auto": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
              }
            }
          },

        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "document_***",
        "creation_date": "1****",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "autocomplete_filter_30": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": "1",
              "max_gram": "30"
            },
            "autocomplete_filter": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": "1",
              "max_gram": "20"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "autocomplete": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "stop",
                "autocomplete_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "autocomplete_30": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "stop",
                "autocomplete_filter_30"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "autocomplete_nonstop": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "autocomplete_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "***",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020499"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Few values are replaced with * for confidentiality reason

Comment: thanks. will go over index mapping. actually its third party service and I'm bit new to elastic search